# How to detect changes from different component

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to detect the component change.

First check my code which work.

The problem here is that this is called init and it is unnecessary to call all the time ... you should only call for a change or when its data ( response ) is  okay.

```
  ngOnInit() {

        this.calendarData(); 
      }
    
      detectChangeUser(){
        this.sharedService.selectedUserType$.subscribe(
          data =>  {  
            if(data === 'changed-view-user-trigger'){
              this.calendarData();
              this.calendarUsers();
            }
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        )
      }
```

I need to detect only when data has a response.

Check also my service.

```
export class SharedService {
  public latestViewSwither: any = null;
  selectedUserType$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.latestViewSwither);
  training$ = this.selectedUserType$.asObservable();
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

  swithViewChanged(e){ 
    this.latestViewSwither = e; 
    this.selectedUserType$.next(e);
  }
}
```

only to detect when data has value.

data === 'changed-view-user-trigger' don't worry about this. I send it from another component only a string...this is not important.
Only important thing is any hook which detects change... I am also trying with ngAfterViewChecked but my software crashes after this...

Comment: It is getting called everytime because you used an `if` statement inside your component. you should check if the response is ok to be sent from your service, otherwise your subscripition will always fire. As a side note, you could use a `.pipe(filter(...))` to trigger subscription only on present data

Comment: When you call the `switchViewChanged` you should put an if statement `if (!!e)...` to call the `next` from the subject. Also you should make your subject private and your subscribe to the `asObservable()` property instead.

Comment: @CapitanFindus code help please?

Comment: @JorgeMussato I don't know how do to this?

Comment: @JorgeMussato can you help me with code provide ?

Comment: @CapitanFindus can you help me with code provide ?

Comment: I posted an answer, sorry I took so long, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` for this. The `BehaviorSubject` has the characteristic that it stores the “current” value. This means that you can always directly get the last emitted value from the `BehaviorSubject`.
See the example below:

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs";

const subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject();

// subscriber 1
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber A:', data);
});

subject.next(Math.random());
subject.next(Math.random());

// subscriber 2
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber B:', data);
});

subject.next(Math.random());

console.log(subject.value)

// output
// Subscriber A: 0.24957144215097515
// Subscriber A: 0.8751123892486292
// Subscriber B: 0.8751123892486292
// Subscriber A: 0.1901322109907977
// Subscriber B: 0.1901322109907977
// 0.1901322109907977
```

Comment: why not import only Subject `import {Subject} from 'rxjs'`, then `subject=new Subject<any>`?

Comment: Okay i don't hear for this..can you provide me example with my code ?

Comment: @Kavinda can you provide me code help with my current code? I cant' understand your example

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that to solve the problem.

service:

```
export class SharedService {
  public latestViewSwither: any = null;
  selectedUserType$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.latestViewSwither);
  training$ = this.selectedUserType$.asObservable();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  swithViewChanged(e){ 
    this.latestViewSwither = e; 
    if (!!e) {
      this.selectedUserType$.next(e);
    }
  }
}
```